# Couldn't send/recieve POST DATA REQUEST between ESP8266 (NodeMCU) and PHP live server

Tags: json, https, arduino-ide, nodemcu, esp8266wifi

I want to connect my NODEMCU wifi module to live server and then comunicate with rest API. While I was calling simple `GET` method with `plain-text` content then everything works fine, problem arises while calling `POST` and `JSON data`. Though my server API seems to work fine on ARC(Rest API testing Application).

**Working With**

1. Windows 10
2. Arduino IDE 1.8.12
3. Linux Live Server (hosted on BIGROCK)
4. Secure Domain (https://)
5. API directory permission is 755

**LIVE SERVER**

```
<?php
if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) != 'POST') {
throw new Exception('Only POST requests are allowed');
}

$content_type = isset($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] : '';
if (stripos($content_type, 'application/json') === false) {
throw new Exception('Content-Type must be application/json');
}

$body = file_get_contents("php://input");
$object = json_decode($body, true);
if (!is_array($object)) {
throw new Exception('Failed to decode JSON object');
}

print_r($object);
?>
```

**Arduino IDE**

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "**********";
const char* password = "**********";
const char* host = "www.ameyakrishi.com";

void setup()
{

Serial.begin(115200);
delay(2000);
Serial.print("[Connecting to "); Serial.print(ssid);
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
{
Serial.print(".");delay(500);
}
Serial.println("  Connected]");delay(1000);
}


void loop()
{
WiFiClient client;
Serial.print("[Connecting to "); Serial.print(host);delay(500);
if (client.connect(host, 80))
{
Serial.println("  Connected]");delay(1000);

String postData = "{\"key\":\"papa\",\"val\":999}";
client.print(String("POST /automation/app.php") + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
"Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
"Content-Type: application/json \r\n" +
"Content-Length: " + postData.length() + "\r\n" +
"Connection: close\r\n" +
"\r\n"
);

while (client.connected() || client.available())
{
if (client.available())
{
String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
Serial.println(line);
}
}

client.stop();
Serial.println("\n[Disconnected]");delay(1000);
}
else
{
Serial.println("connection failed!]");delay(1000);
client.stop();
}
delay(30000);

}
```

**Serial Monitor Output**
All connections are succeed and then print the `500 Internal Server Error` response in  format.

Comment: Can you check your PHP error log and add your error message from the logs? This will help to solve the issue.

Comment: thank you @Christoph to sahre your thought.. but I think the issue with the esp module code

Comment: People here are willing to help but they need something concrete. In this case the `500 Internal Server Error` just indicates that something failed but it's not displaying the real error. So for me and for the other readers it will help seeing the full error message generated by your app (+ the stack trace next to it). As of now it's simply guessing.